# Internet Explorer 10 freezing when accessing Siebel 7.5

Tags: internet-explorer

I am seeing a Windows 8 machine running IE 10 which is having issues causing it to get slower and slower and ultimately freeze after trying to access a Siebel 7.5 site.

It also hangs when trying to connect to the site itself. Another machine running Windows 7 + IE10 seems to run it fine, but only after removing Norton 360 and resetting the IE settings.

Comment: If this only happens with this one site, and I assume siebel is a CRM package, should you not ask them direct? However, load IE in safe mode and see if the same issues persist, also try a different browser. If the issue is only that site then you have answered your own question really...

Comment: If you know that the issue is possibly due to IE settings or the AV, what have you done on the computer with the issue? Did you try configuring IE or the AV?

Comment: I've removed Norton 360 and reset IE settings. This has worked fine on a Windows 7 machine, but not on a Windows 8 machine.

Comment: Did you try a different browser?